# Slice a line by portion in Leaflet

Tags: leaflet

I have some lines which need to be sliced by a certain portion.

I can get the outcome by using turf.lineSliceAlong function, something like:

```
totalLength = turf.length(myLine);
markerSliced = totalLength * (1 - leftPortion);
slicedLine = turf.lineSliceAlong(myLine, markerSliced, totalLength);
```

I'm wondering is there a better way of doing this by using pure Leaflet functions?

Comment: You ask if "there is a better way". What would be criteria for "better"?

Comment: I’m open to any suggestions, but preferred using less plugins or turf. Thanks.

Comment: All Leaflet polyline methods are descibed here https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.7.1.html#polyline and here https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.7.1.html#polyutil, so you are out of luck with native Leaflet methods. If you don't like plugins, you'll have to write your own function.

Comment: ok, thanks for making it clear.